# Optimistic UI with SwiftUI Toggle

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a feature with a `Toggle` that fires off a network request each time the `Toggle` changes state. Here's the code I have so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    // ...
    Toggle(isOn: $viewModel.isOn)
      .onChanged(of: viewModel.isOn) {
        viewModel.updatePreference(isOn: viewModel.isOn)
      }
  }
} 

@MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isOn: Bool = true

  func updatePreference(isOn: Bool) {
    Task {
      var request = URLRequest(...)
      do {
        _ = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
      } catch { 
        isOn = !isOn
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the network request fails, I reset the `isOn` property to the opposite value.

The problem is my implementation will go into an infinite loop because I'm resetting the state of the `Toggle` is causing a network call to fire.

How might I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the logic a little, instead of using a `Toggle` and operating on the premise that the call will succeed I would use a `Button` and wait for success to change the value.

```
// View State is better handled in a `struct`, ObservableObjects are very inneficient.
struct ViewModel {
    var isOn: Bool  = false
    
    mutating func updatePreference() async throws {
        //Floating `Task` is considered bad practice, maximise the efficiency of async/await  
        let newValue = !isOn

        var request = URLRequest(url: .init(string: "")!)
        // Use !isOn in the call

        do {
            _ = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            self.isOn = newValue //Once mutation is validated mutate the bool
        } catch {
            //Make no changes on throw
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `View` you can modify the `View` when the call is successful.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AutoToggleView: View {
    //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state
    // It is better to handle View State changes with a struct.
    @Binding var viewModel: ViewModel
    // Keep track of when the call is being made.
    @State private var flipping: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            flipping.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: viewModel.isOn ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                .overlay(content: {
                    if flipping {
                        ProgressView() //Show a progress view while the call is being made.
                    }
                })
                .task(id: flipping) {
                    guard flipping else {
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.updatePreference()
                    } catch {
                        print(error) //Show error to user
                    }
                    flipping = false //Let the view know the call is done
                }
        }).disabled(flipping) //Disable the button when the call is being made to prevent multiple calls.
    }
}
```

You can make the `Button` look like a `Toggle` if that is your requirement.

```
struct AutoToggleView: View {
    //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state
    // It is better to handle View State changes with a struct.
    @State private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    // Keep track of when the call is being made.
    @State private var flipping: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            flipping.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Capsule()
                .fill(viewModel.isOn ? Color.green : Color.gray)
                .aspectRatio(1.75, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50)
                .overlay {
                    HStack{
                        if !viewModel.isOn {
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.white)
                            .padding(2)
                            .overlay(content: {
                                if flipping {
                                    ProgressView() //Show a progress view while the call is being made.
                                }
                            })
                        if viewModel.isOn {
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .task(id: flipping) {
                    guard flipping else {
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.updatePreference()
                    } catch {
                        print(error) //Show error to user
                    }
                    flipping = false //Let the view know the call is done
                }
        }).disabled(flipping) //Disable the button when the call is being made to prevent multiple calls.
    }
}
```